# The requested resource is not available (HTTP 404) - Jersey and Spring integration

Tags: tomcat, jersey

I get the above mentioned error message when trying to invoke GET method on users resource : http://localhost:8080/Trempiada/users/12345.
Or just enter the project's main URI : http://localhost:8080/Trempiada.
I'm having Spring's listener for DI and the tomcat server loads without any exception.
Here is my web.xml file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

      <!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use JavaConfigWebApplicationContext
         instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

        <!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
         fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>org.sharon.trempiada.resources.ResourcesConfiguration org.sharon.trempiada.services.ServicesConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>trempiada</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.sharon.trempiada.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>trempiada</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

What should I check and where could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context path of your webapp in Tomcat is by default based on the war file name.  So, a context path of `Trempiada` implies the war file name is `Trempiada-1.0.war`.  Can you confirm that this is this the case?  If not, you'll need to adjust your URL to include the actual context path.  Tomcat usually logs this during startup.

The second part of this is the resource endpoint.  To match the URL you provided, you need a resource class as follows:

```
@Path("users")
public class UserResource {
    ...
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("{id:\\d+}")
    public User getUser() {
        // Return user object.
    }
}
```

If you do this, you'll be able to access your endpoint at `http://localhost:8080/Trempiada/users/12345`.

Comment: Solved my problem. I didn't notive it's case sensitive (Trempiada != trempiada) , and I thought that the context is based on the webapp name like it's displayed under the "Servers/Tomcat" tab in eclipse.